# Will developing Flutter plugin with Kotlin make any difference with one written in Java?

Tags: flutter

It's probably not a programming question and a bit too generic but I can't find any resource about the differences of writing plugin for flutter using Kotlin vs Java. From my research, almost every plugin in pub.dev that I found is written in Java. I don't say Java is bad but I personally prefer Kotlin over Java because of the syntax.

I'm planning to build native code to interact with native libs both on iOS and Android for my project since I couldn't find any plugin that satisfy the project requirements. I'd like to share it on pubdev when it's done (hopefully) so I have to think twice before writing it.

The question is, if I do so (developing Kotlin-based plugin), will it make any difference? Like maybe requires the user to add some extra configuration to their project? Or maybe any Flutter project that uses Java can't use my package? and.. will it do the same for iOS (using Swift over Objective-C)? The docs is telling us that we can switch both in between, but doesn't tell any side effects about it.

Comment: Interesting question, you should obviously go for whatever is easier for you, but the user might have to have some extra configuration if you make it with Kotlin. For example, if I make a library with JQuery the user will need to have jQuery configuration to use it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about. I understand the flow for web development stuffs but I'd like to know about it in android-ios development using flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is nothing to worry about. Flutter apps are now by default created with Kotlin/Swift and not with Java/ObjC. Of course if someone has an ultra old Flutter configuration, then he might have some problems but I wouldn't concern myself with it.

All the native plugin code is converted to a Gradle dependency or Pod(spec) dependency. The app developer doesn't have to care about it and that is a good thing.